# Python key changer program

Tags: python, pyautogui, msvcrt, windows-key

I have got a keyboard with a non-working windows key.
I tried to fix it with Python if I press the > key, the program will press the windows key, but it's not working.
Here's the code:

```
    import msvcrt
    import pyautogui
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
            if key_stroke == b'>':
                pyautogui.press('super')
                print(key_stroke)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Which keyboard-layout do you use? The [US keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg) ?

Comment: Depending on the OS you are on, there are also keyboard-mapping tools like [XKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_keyboard_extension) on Linux, [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/) on Windows, and [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) on macOS.

Comment: @hc_dev suggests a good alternative. It's much better to use windows developed tools that are built for this, rather than creating a script - [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remap keys in python, the *keyboard* module is what you are looking for.

Please install keyboard package first (pip install keyboard). [Documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api)

The *remap_hotkey* function does exactly what you need.

*keyboard.wait* blocks the execution of the code until a key is pressed.

```
import keyboard

keyboard.remap_hotkey("Shift+.", "windows")

while True:
    keyboard.wait()
```

Note that "Shift+." may change depending on your keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

To press ">" you need to press two keys "shift" + ".", when you release the "." key you registered ">" being a keystroke. but till that time you have not released the "shift" key.

In a nutshell when you execute pyautogui.press('super') in line 7, you are already pressing the "shift" key and then sending the "super" key command.

Solution to your problem is simple, release the "shift" key before sending the pyautogui.press('super') cmd.

The below code will resolve your problem.

Please install pynput package first (pip install pynput). [Documentation for pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Solution - 1 (Modifying your code)

```
import msvcrt
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard

kb = keyboard.Controller()

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
        if key_stroke == b'>':
            kb.release(keyboard.Key.shift)
            pyautogui.press('super')
            print(key_stroke)
```

Solution - 2 (This will give you more control over your keyboard events)
To exit from the shell press the "Esc" key.

```
from pynput import keyboard

kb = keyboard.Controller()

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if hasattr(key, 'char') and key.char == ">":
        kb.release(keyboard.Key.shift)
        kb.press(keyboard.Key.cmd)
        kb.release(keyboard.Key.cmd)
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```